# Adding new option in the action button of sugarCRM

Tags: contacts, sugarcrm

I am fairly new to the sugar but a pro at php.

I am trying to add an option "Print" in the action button/dropdown at the Contacts list view of the sugarCRM but cannot find its code.

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Thanks,
tanay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a blog post which should help:

http://developer.sugarcrm.com/2010/11/22/howto-adding-your-own-listview-action-items/

Comment: Thank you jmertic! It did help me to create a link and subsequently the action page.

Comment: this code worked fine at my local server but it is not working at the live server, any idea what am I missing -

Comment: return <<<EOHTML 
<a href='#' style='width: 150px' class='menuItem' 
    onmouseover='hiliteItem(this,"yes");' onmouseout='unhiliteItem(this);' 
    onclick="sugarListView.get_checks(); 
            if(sugarListView.get_checks_count() < 1) { 
                alert('{$app_strings['LBL_LISTVIEW_NO_SELECTED']}'); 
                return false; 
            } 
            document.MassUpdate.action.value='displaypassedids'; 
            document.MassUpdate.submit();"> 
    Printing Label 
    </a> 
EOHTML;